# Window 10 error running docker nanoserver

Tags: windows, docker

Tried to recreate someone's docker error and I ran into my own error.  I had to switch to windows containers and reboot.  It downloaded the images but error'd on running it.  No logs in the docker logs nano.  On a surface pro 4 running Windows 10 Pro winver 1709 build 17025.1000 64-bit

```
PS C:\Users\dskow\docker> docker run -d --name nano microsoft/nanoserver
Unable to find image 'microsoft/nanoserver:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from microsoft/nanoserver
bce2fbc256ea: Pull complete
4806a44e00a0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:3331d7e40d93e8a3ea617450701a4f6550c699a673348b82fdc6fc01b9c44500
Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/nanoserver:latest
0d017c5adcbc5b04bb8f59c61a431bd5763c8792b97bc4fc400ffc48f0feab00
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe:
Error response from daemon:
container 0d017c5adcbc5b04bb8f59c61a431bd5763c8792b97bc4fc400ffc48f0feab00 encountered an 
error during CreateContainer: 
failure in a Windows system call: 
The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found. (0x3ab6)
extra info:
{
   "SystemType": "Container",
   "Name": "0d017c5adcbc5b04bb8f59c61a431bd5763c8792b97bc4fc400ffc48f0feab00",
   "Owner": "docker",
   "IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot": true,
   "LayerFolderPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\0d017c5adcbc5b04bb8f59c61a431bd5763c8792b97bc4fc400ffc48f0feab00",
   "Layers": [
   {
     "ID": "d3abf9e6-799a-5aa3-89a0-0f5fef546183",
     "Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\bc039df4c6ed43722c34bdf4ed7cc022b1b24c2f7edd8221dbb8d7645c2fdd10"},
     {"ID": "4b849cd7-812a-5d2d-8b80-b0ca73856b43",
     "Path": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8b68ab3315c2e26fe5c6fe5e616f0d13c502d421f7ca3d6160fddf008e29a02e"
     }],
     "HostName": "0d017c5adcbc",
     "HvPartition": true,
     "EndpointList": ["70d55b67-4127-4404-aae1-b3522ed89f1b"],
     "HvRuntime": {
       "ImagePath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\bc039df4c6ed43722c34bdf4ed7cc022b1b24c2f7edd8221dbb8d7645c2fdd10\\UtilityVM"
},
         "AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery": true
}.
PS C:\Users\dskow\docker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found and tried the workaround to the Microsoft bug on the web.  They are aware of the issue.

> This is a bug in Windows and we have a fix coming in the next flight...
>   As a workaround you can temporarily disable our cloning optimization by creating a registry key and rebooting or restarting the vmcompute service.
>   reg ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\Containers" /v TemplateVmCount /t REG_DWORD /d 0
>
> But be sure to delete the key after you take the next flight or your container starts will remain slower...

Original message on github https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1302